# How to make variables restart when the game restarts?

Tags: unity

My game is all in one scene so when my player dies and the user clicks restart the game (when it shows the game over screen) the script below doesn't restart with it so the enemies are still going fast when the user is replaying the game. How do I make it restart when the game restarts?

```
if (Score % 10 == 0) {
    //Increment movespeed variable from Movement script
    Movement.movespeed += 4;
}
```

This is used in my score script. The `Movement.movespeed` is a reference to my movement script attach to my enemies making them go faster when the player collects 10 points.

Answer (score 1):

While not very Unity-specific, my personal approach to this would be to add a custom `void ResetGame()` method, that you call when the user clicks to restart the game.

In `ResetGame`, you would set all the values that need to be reset to their defaults, and that way all the variables would start again from where they started initially.

So something along the lines of

```
private void ResetGame() {
    Movement.movespeed = 1;  // Or whatever your initial value was.
    ResetScene();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I just wanted to know Should I add this to my score script???

Comment: The best approach would obviously be to reset the variables in the script that manages those variables, and call the methods that reset those variables from the main script that handles the resetting.

Comment: okay thank you but im getting an two errors with ResetScene();. error: error CS0031: Constant value `0.2' cannot be converted to a `int' and The name `ResetScene' does not exist in the current context

Comment: The code is pseudo-code. There probably isn't a method called `ResetScene()` in Unity. Just replace it with whatever you use to reset the actors and such. For your other error, as the error message very clearly says: you can put a **double** value to an **int** variable.